# How can I control the number of output files from a Spark SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Creating a table from a Spark SQL SELECT, we end up generating too many files. How can we limit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from spark 2.4 you can hint the query to control the output:

```
INSERT ... SELECT /*+ COALESCE(numPartitions) */ ...
INSERT ... SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(numPartitions) */ ...
```

For example, this would generate 5 files:

```
CREATE TABLE business.clients
AS 
SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(5) */
       client_id,
       country,
       wallet
FROM business.users;
```

Before Spark 2.4, a way would be to limit the number of partitions for the whole query:

```
SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 5;
```

But this would potentially impact the process performance.

More information here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24940

Comment: What is this ? A blog ?

Comment: It's a way to find it next time I need it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Good to know. Cheers!